# Как сохранить значения парсинга JSON в массив в ArduinoJson

Tags: массивы, json, парсер, arduino, parse

Ардуинщики, помогите пожалуйста! К примеру, у меня есть документ JSON для парсинга (либа ArduinoJson):

```
{
  "id": [
    1,
    7,
    32,
    9656
  ]
}
```

Мне нужно сохранить значения, чтобы они выглядели так:

**ids[0] = 1,**

**ids[1] = 7,**

**ids[2] = 32 и так далее.**

На данный момент делаю так (знаю, что это в корне неправильно, но иначе не знаю как):

*Пропущу этап запроса по ссылке*

```
char json[500];
  getids.toCharArray(json, 500);
  Serial.println(json);
  StaticJsonDocument <500> doc;
  DeserializationError err = deserializeJson(doc, json);
```

Затем просто пытаюсь присвоить значения массиву :

```
int ids[16] = {doc["id"]};
```

Но по факту, когда вывожу ids[0], то получаю 0
Также проблема в том, что я заранее не знаю, сколько элементов будет в этом массиве - этот файл регулярно редактируется в приложении на телефон, и в файле JSON может меняться количество этих айди. Сейчас их 4, но это в качестве примера, т.к. их количество неизвестно, что заставляет сделать динамический массив, а не задавать его самому, как я задал (16)

ArduinoJSON ассистент предлагает такой вариант:

```
JsonArray id = doc["id"];
int id_0 = id[0]; // 1
int id_1 = id[1]; // 7
int id_2 = id[2]; // 1337
int id_3 = id[3]; // 9656
```

Но это не то, ведь, повторюсь, я не знаю количество элементов заранее.

Это мой первый вопрос на Stackoverflow, поэтому извините, если я задал его неправильно

Comment: Уточните что именно вызвало трудности? указанная библиотека документирована и содержит примеры использования. p.s. пример JSON в вопросе - содержит ошибку, и валидацию не пройдет :)

Comment: К документации обращался, но она не особо помогла. Проблема в том, что если парсить эти значения простым int, то он найдёт их все по порядку, но присвоит последнее значение, то есть 6. Нужно как-то сделать так, чтобы на каждом этапе значения записывались в массив, что у меня не получается сделать. По поводу ошибки в JSON - это лишь небольшой кусок, для примера, строки string_text парсятся и записываются без проблем

Comment: Покажите ваш json(читай первый комментарий) и код, чтоб мы могли вам помочь :)

Comment: Исправил структуру вопроса, надеюсь, теперь лучше

Comment: Рас https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsonarray/size/, два http://arduino.ru/forum/programmirovanie/kak-sozdat-dinamicheskii-massiv-arduino, в сумме - ответ на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё гораздо проще, можно просто использовать

```
JsonArray ids = doc["id"];
```

и использовать внутри функций как ids[1]